# retrofit2: adding RequestInterceptor

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Guys please am trying to upgrade from **retrofit 1** to **retrofit 2** but am having a hard time adding a request interceptor for all requests.
In **retrofit 1**, I achieved it by doing something like this;

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String token) {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constant.APP_URL);
    builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("token", token);
        }
    });
    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();

    return adapter.create(serviceClass);
}
```

But i just cant get my head around this in **retrofit 2**... Please does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dependencies block add:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

In your `Retrofit` service class add:

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
```

then add:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(client) // this is the line you care about
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: nice i will give it a try

Comment: @DhãtDhøpëBwøūyÇüzzy, I can also help you use Stetho Interceptors as well. Let me know.

Comment: @DhãtDhøpëBwøūyÇüzzy, did it work? If so mark the question as answered, if not let me know what issue you're having.